# Global Variable in buttons

Tags: java

How do I make the exit button a global variable? I am making a gui for my teacher for a grade and I have to make it 'global' so the jframe can get to it. Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class StudentGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public StudentGUI()
    {
    super("StudentGUI Frame");



      //TopPanel
     TopPanel tp;
     tp=new TopPanel();

     Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);
     tp.setPreferredSize(d);
     this.add (tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
     tp.setVisible(true);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.setSize(800,600);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);

        tp.setVisible(true);

        //TopPanel End


        //BottomPanel
        BottomPanel bp;
     bp=new BottomPanel();


     this.add (bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     tp.setVisible(true);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.setSize(800,600);

        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);

        //BottomPanel End

        //MiddlePanel 

    MiddlePanel mp;
     mp=new MiddlePanel();


     this.add (mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     mp.setVisible(true);
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     this.setSize(800,600);

        //MiddlePanel End

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                  "Do you want to close the window?", 
                                  "Choose", 
                                  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);


//ExitBtn.addActionListener(this);

}
}
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new StudentGUI();
    }


}
```

Now that is the frame. Here is the panel that is having the problem to get the exit button to do the action performed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {

public String findbtn="";
public String insertBtn="";
public String updateBtn="";
public String deleteBtn="";
Button exitBtn;

public BottomPanel() {
   JButton findbtn;
     findbtn=new JButton("Find");
        add(findbtn);

           JButton insertBtn;
     insertBtn=new JButton("Insert");
        add(insertBtn);

           JButton updateBtn;
     updateBtn=new JButton("Update");
        add(updateBtn);

           JButton deleteBtn;
     deleteBtn=new JButton("Delete");
        add(deleteBtn);

        JButton exitBtn;
     exitBtn=new JButton("Exit");
        add(exitBtn);



}
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to access the button from the main frame if you already can see it in your GUI, so what all you have to do is add a `ActionListener` to the exit button inside the `ButtonPanel` and your problem will be solved.

**For Example:**

```
exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to add it from frame class. You can do it in panel class only. But then also if you want from frame class then keep this in mind that
Your exitbtn in  BottomPanel class is package private so you can access it only if the frame class is in same package. Next just where you are adding action listener write

```
bp.extBtn.addActionListener(this)
```

Comment: Keeps saying package bp.exitBtn.addActionListener(this); the bp doesnt exist, help?